# Exam exceptions for student with disabilities

Tags: professorship, ethics, disability

I am registered as a psychologically disabled student with my University, and (for disability reasons) have asked my professor to allow me to take the exam at a date later than the ordinarily scheduled time.  I have not received a response from my professor yet; my guess is that she is hesitant to agree to this exception for several reasons. One, is the notion that I might have some kind of advantage over the rest of the class. Second, should my professor make modifications to the exam (e.g. change problems, make it harder) for my exam, then she may argue that the other students' exams will have to be graded differently from mine, and that's unfair. Third, the exam is scheduled at the normal class time, 10:00 AM - 10:50 AM, so it can be argued that if a student attends class regularly at those times, then there is no reason why the student should need to take the exam at a different time.

My professor hasn't said any of the above (yet) and I don't read minds; this is just my best guess of what she will think of my request. University policy leaves the decision on such an exception entirely up to the professor. (No department in the University has authority to influence her decision. Not even the office of disability services can influence her decision in this case.)

From your experiences at universities, how do most professors typically respond to such exceptions? For you professors, does the exception I'm requesting appear reasonable to you? Are there any other reasons you can think of for why the professor would/should **not** grant me an exception for the exam?

Comment: I reposted this under a new name to protect my identity.

Comment: What is your justification for taking the exam at a later date? You need more time to prepare than others? In some tests (SAT, I believe) students with challenges like yours are simply given _extra time_. However, the question I would ask any of my students is "Why should you get a different test as opposed to simply getting more time to take the same test as everyone else?"

Comment: Is your disability accommodation covered by the ADA in the US? If so, does your accomodation specify that you are allowed to reschedule an exam at your convenience? If not, why exactly do you think you are entitled to such an accommodation?

Comment: @earthling I am not asking for a **different** test, necessarily, unless the professor **wants** to give a different one. I just expect she would, because of the possibility that students will talk about the exam.

Answer (score 8):

Exceptions can always be made under certain circumstances. Interestingly in your long and detailed question, there is no trace of a reason for requesting a delay other than your general condition, which I cannot see as a reason by itself. The university/department probably has some rules or policies for such cases. There are usually ways for people with different disabilities to take an exam in parallel with the scheduled exam in a a separate room, sometimes with specific tools and help. I can for example see that hospitalization and family funeral can be clear cases for such exceptions.

So if an exception is made, what would you have to expect? To provide exactly the same exam twice seems extremely unlikely for the reasons you provide. So from the teacher perspective, making a new exam is not something to take lightly, it requires a lot of work (if done seriously). In other words, you would get a different exam designed to be of equal difficulty. From a student perspective a new exam can always appear either easier or more difficult based on what and how well you have studied but in general, the exam would not intentionally be made more difficult.

Comment: _no trace of a reason for requesting a delay_ — Nor should there be!  The request was apparently channeled through the OP's university's disability office, who is charged with determining whether accommodations are appropriate.  The specific condition that justifies the accommodations is none of the instructor's damn business (or ours).  That said, I agree with @earthling's comment on the original post — requests for _extra exam time_ and _a less distracting exam environment_ are fairly standard; requests for _extra preparation time_ are not.

Comment: Where in "... and (for disability reasons) have asked my professor to allow me to take the exam at a date later than the ordinarily scheduled time" do you read "channeled through the OP's univesity diability office"?

Comment: "Not even the office of disability services can influence her decision in this case."

Comment: @JeffE I agree with Peter Jansson. If a student in the US is entitled to an accommodation under the ADA then the instructor **must** provide that accommodation. Since the OP said it is at the instructor's discretion I am assuming that this is not part of an ADA accommodation. The instructor is well within their rights to ignore such a request, particularly without justification. Providing accommodations beyond ADA requirements is not fair to other students.

Comment: @JoeHass: I agree!!  US professors are required to provide accommodation under ADA (given appropriate documentation from people who are actually qualified to judge the need for such accommodation), but we have wide discretion in exactly **how** we provide that accommodation.  It looks like the OP is trying a little too hard to exploit that discretion.

Comment: @JeffE, to your first comment, you're correct about most, standard requests being under the authority of the Disabilities Office. In my case, however, the request is non-standard. The University policy on accommodations for students with disabilities, most certainly has ADA at its foundation, but has added additional provisions. So just because something is not in ADA does not mean it's not in my University's policy for disabled students. I disagree about "trying too hard to **exploit** that discretion". The word **exploit** has negative connotations. I don't see how I am "trying too hard".

Comment: @PeterJansson, there is only so much detail I am willing to volunteer. (You read my comment under my question?). But even without the details, you've given a very helpful response. What specifics would you have wanted to know?

Comment: @Necron It is not details about your condition that matters but rather what conditions the university provide to you that interests me. If they provide possibility to take exams late is quite different from you requesting a late exam for other reasons. So it is not the detail of the reason but whether or not it is part of your plan with the U. that makes a difference to how to relate to the problem o the exam.

Comment: _In my case, however, the request is non-standard._ — Ah. In that case, you should realistically expect your request to be refused, unless you can convince the Disability Office (that is, turn it into a standard request).

Comment: @PeterJansson: at my University, the (Disabilities Support Services) **DSS** Office handles issues of this sort. There are many possible accommodations that DSS can make. and I quicklu reviewed the policy with an avvisor. The Policy essentially categorizes the rules into 2 groups:

Comment: @PeterJansson: 1.  Standard accommodations for students, e.g. 1.5 time on exams. extended due dates, test in parallel, and on. DSS students may also register to take the exam at the normal class time, or should the professor agree,, on a different date (it is highly encouraged to take the exam on the same date as the rest of the class.

Comment: @JeffE 2. Then the University policy allows DSS students, like any student, to make an informal aragreement to take the exam at a different date, under extenuating circumstances. Of course, the professor is free to accept or reject. I have seen professors make exceptions for non-disabled students. If you knew the full nature of the disability (which is beyond what I will disclose here), then this exception; my request to take the exam at a later date may (but may not) appear more reasonable.